# Lifetime of static members of a View when its owner activity is stopped

Tags: android, android-activity, static

My `MainActivity` spans some (ie. 4) webviews `CustomWebView`. This class has a static method **BROADCAST** that broadcast some message to all instantiated children.

- so inside the activity context, i can do

  ```
  CustomWebView.BROADCAST (BECOME_RED)
  ```

  and all CustomWebViews would become red.
- All is fine but now my main activity spans a `subactivity` (ie. select a picture activity). The original activity becomes stopped (its `onstop()` called blah blah blah)

So... What would happen now, in the context of this new subactivity, with its parent activity stopped, should I do:

```
CustomWebView.BROADCAST (BECOME_RED)
```

- I've seen it "works" but dont really understand the implications of the owner activity being stopped and I messing with its views accessing them "illegally" from a static context.
- What about if the static method access the View, but only non-view related stuff such as an ArrayList?
- What about if the static method does NOT access a child instance, but uses exclusively static variables? Does it make a different?
- What about the lifetime of the View object (static stuff mainly) when the activity is stopped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static members of class live as long as class is loaded (also, as long as JVM is running in case of android). But views are created with a context ( also Activity )   and have pretty intimate private relation  - AFAIK,  they should not be used with multiple activities.

Activity stop does not mean that it is destroyed - it can be reactivated at later time.  View instances survive this.

Comment: sorry for the late accept, had stopped Android development for a while but now 100% into it. Thanx for the reply!